# finding variable relation in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, regression-testing

I have a data-set  which has columns as

x1  x2  x3  x4  x5   y

all of them has integer / float value and Y values ranges from 98,000 to 1,10,000

If I want to find the relationship between x1 and y , x2 and y ... x5 and y and come up with

y = A.x1+c

how should i do it?

I tried plotting graphs and also tried lm() and fit() functions in R.

```
fit <- lm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5,data=data)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both")
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should use some specialsed package that find best linear/relation between `y` and variable `xi`. You can see for example `leaps` package.

You can also find the relation by looping over all your xi. Here one way to do it. Firest I warp you code in a function. And I use the `dot formula` notation.

```
lm_col <-
  function(var,data){
    fit <- lm(y~.,subset(data,select=c('y',var)))
    stepAIC(fit, direction="both")
  }
```

Then you loop over all you variables using `lapply`:

```
 lapply(paste0('x',seq(5)),lm_col,data=dat)
```

You can test this using this data:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*10),ncol=6))
colnames(dat) <- c(paste0('x',seq(5)),'y')
```

But as I said at the beginning, I don't think that this is the best way to do what you want to do ( not very clear) statistically speaking.